# Typescript unit test private and protected methods

Tags: typescript, jasmine, mocha.js, webstorm, chai

I want to be able to test private `Typescript` methods. Please skip your lecture of `why this is a bad idea`. I've heard it.

Here is a demo code:

```
class MyClass {
    age: number

    private ageAsString(): string {
        return '15'
    }
}
```

Here are my options in the test file:

1 - Write `//@ts-ignore` which allows TS to compile this line. This gets inconvenient very quickly when you're calling 200 x `expect()`s. But I couldn't find a way to do this block based of file based.

```
it('Test ageAsString', () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    expect(new MyClass().ageAsString()).to.equal('15')
})
```

2 - Turning a class object to `any` object. This disables autocomplete and refactoring features I get from TS and my IDE. It seems like a good idea at first but 1 month later it will either break 200 of my test cases or create some unforeseen bugs.

```
it('Test ageAsString', () => {
    const anyClass: any = new MyClass
    expect(anyClass.ageAsString()).to.equal('15')
})
```

3 - Can use array access, which works but creates the same problems as #2.

```
it('Test ageAsString', () => {
    expect(new MyClass()['ageAsString']()).to.equal('15')
})
```

I want to somehow be able to test these methods without having the downsides. Right now I have 2 choices, both are bad.

1. Skip writing specific detailed unit tests
2. Make method public

Please give me a 3rd option

Comment: If you really want to call it that badly, make it public. Otherwise, just use the other MyClass method that calls this private method and make sure it returns the correct result.

Comment: But I do agree that testing your private methods is very unnecessary if you are actually testing all your public methods.

Comment: Testing smaller private functions is easier and more readable than testing larger public functions

Comment: If you class is that large then your testworthy private methods should probably be public functions of some other service which has only that responsibility.

Comment: That's not always the case. Just imagine what's behind the `getGoogleSearchResult()` method. This should obviously be a public method, but the `boostGoogleSearchWithAI()` method is only called from the previous method therefore should be private. But it is complex as hell and therefore needs to be tested separately.

Comment: Sure, but you can just mock the other moving parts within `getGooleSearchResult`, call `getGoogleSearchResult` with your different cases, and verify that the result is correct (which includes whatever `boostGoogleSearchWithAI()` was suppposed to do).

Comment: You can, but it would be easier and simpler, just to be able to isolate to a single method than to deal with mocking.

Comment: Apparently it's not easier and simpler, hence why this question has no other answers. :D

Comment: Why is it not simpler? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One other way of testing protected methods is to create a Fake class and extend your class that needs to be tested.

```
class MyClass {
  protected test() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```
class FakeMyClass extends MyClass {
  public test() {
    return super.test();
  }
}
```

```
it('test', () => {
    const myClass = new FakeMyClass();
    expect(myClass.test()).to.true;
})
```